# Is it possible somehow "rescue" segmentation fault on Ruby

Tags: ruby, segmentation-fault

I have a Ruby script, which uses one external lib.
Sometimes script exits with segmentation fault,
when uses this lib and I must to rerun it.
Is it possible to somehow rescue this error by extracting fragment,
which has dangerous code to separate process or something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [neversaydie](https://github.com/tenderlove/neversaydie#readme) gem to rescue segmentation faults.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is incredibly dangerous; once you're segfaulted, all bets are off on memory corruption and process state.  If you do decide to rescue SEGVs, you should clean up and exit the running process as quickly as possible, and test very very well.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not compliles under my operating system,
I'll try to figure out how to fix issue.